# Changing php variable value based on if user is already signed up

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am using two mysql tables to create a class registration system. The classes table lists all the classes available and the user_classes keeps track of the classes the user has signed up for. The structure of each table is as follows:

classes table

class_id, class_department, class_number, class_name

user_classes table

id, user_id, class_id_fk

I need to write a mysql sql to identify if a user is already signed up for a class. If they are I want to display a link that says "already registered" and if not I want to display a link that says "register".

I know I need to use an if/else statement after the sql statement but I'm not sure how to construct the sql in-order to yield a variable that I can run the if/else statement on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. You need to at least try.

Comment: there are too many ways to do this, do search/try something.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_classes WHERE user_id = ? AND class_id_fk = ?` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) as cnt FROM classes 
JOIN user_classes ON user_classes.class_id_fk=classes.id 
WHERE user_classes.user_id=? AND classes.id=?";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$_SESSION['user_id'], $classID);

// Will equal 0 if the user has not signed up
$hasSignedUp = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if($hasSignedUp > 0){
     echo "Aleady Registered";
} else {
     echo "Register";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `user_classes` WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `class_id_fk` = 1;
```

This SQL query should return 1 or 0 depending upon whether the user with id 1 is signed up to class with id 1.

Now that you have the SQL query you want to run, you will need to learn how to manipulate your database from PHP. The link below should help you out with that.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp